# SQL SERVER - delimited identifiers [] don't work when running an Update Query on a Linked Server table

Tags: sql, linked-server, sql-server-2014

So I have a linked server (access mdb database) in SQL SERVER. I have a table in there called `XX2 Sectors` (yes i know that white spaces in table names/columns are a bad practice but I don't have any control over it in this case).

When I run a SELECT query in a form

```
 SELECT * FROM [Server_Name]...[XX2 Sectors]
```

it works completely fine, BUT when I am running and UPDATE query on this table e.g.

```
UPDATE [Server_Name]...[XX2 Sectors] SET Column_Name = 'Variable' WHERE     
Column_Name = 'whatever'`
```

> I get an error: OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "Server_Name" returned message "The Microsoft Access database engine cannot find the input table or query 'XX2'. Make sure it exists and that its name is spelled correctly."

-> So basicaly it cuts off the table name at the white space point which [] should prevent... But if I rename the table from `XX2 Sectors` to `XX2_Sectors` -> effectively removing the white space then the UPDATE query works fine.

Any thoughts? I think i tried everything and I am now at a loss...

Thank you.

Comment: You should include all parts of the four name refereence:  `UPDATE [server].[database].[schema].[table] . . .`

Comment: It's an access database there is nothing more in there just server and table name. As stated before it works fine when I am using the SELECT statement or rename the table to not have white spaces it works fine -> so that eliminates that as a possible problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATED: So the answer was that for some reason when you use linked server is SQL Sever (bug or not I don't know) but if you try to update a filed table in the Linked Datasheet (and it is Access) based on the value of the field it won't work unless you update something else as well or choose another criteria. For Example:

```
UPDATE TABLE SET FIELD1 = Z WHERE FIELD1 = X
```

will not work, BUT

```
UPDATE TABLE SET FIELD1 = Z WHERE FIELD2 = X
```

OR

```
UPDATE TABLE SET FIELD1 = Z, FILED2 = F WHERE FIELD1 = Y
```

OR

```
UPDATE TABLE SET FIELD1 = Z, FIELD2 = FIELD2 WHERE FIELD1 = X
```

Will work fine.

-------- OLD ANSWER BELOW ------

After 3 hours I found the solution for this problem which unfortunately means there is no solution as the problem resolved itself after I had launch...

Comment: Yeah I think the problem was that the query tab in the SQL managment studio became buggy (as it usually happens with everything microsoft) and opening a new query tab might of solved it or it was just a bizarre coincidence.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [QUOTENAME](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176114.aspx).

> Returns a Unicode string with the delimiters added to make the input
>   string a valid SQL Server delimited identifier.

`QOUTENAME(XX2 Sectors)` instead of `[XX2 Sectors]`

Comment: If I use `UPDATE [DR2_SECTORS]...QOUTENAME(DR2 Sectors)` then I have en error `Incorrect syntax near 'Sectors'.` but if I use `UPDATE [DR2_SECTORS]...[QOUTENAME(DR2 Sectors)]` I get an error `The OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "Server_Name" does not contain the table "QOUTENAME(XX2 Sectors)". The table either does not exist or the current user does not have permissions on that table.`

Comment: If problem resolved itself, still better use `QOUTENAME` instead of `[]`